# Redirect not working using Python and Flask to build a user registration page

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a homework assignment due that is nearly complete. However, I'm having a little trouble with the redirect to another template the welcomes the user with a brief welcome and the submitted users name after submit. Could someone take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template
import cgi
import os
import jinja2
import re

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

@app.route("/")
def index():
    template = jinja_env.get_template('index.html')
    return template.render()

@app.route("/validate-signup", methods = ['POST'])
def validate_signup():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    verifypword = request.form['verifypword']
    email = request.form['email']

    user_error = ""
    pass_error = ""
    verifypass_error = ""
    email_error = ""    

    if not username.isalpha():
        user_error = "Please enter User Name"
        username = ""
    elif not re.match("^[a-zA-Z]{3,7}$", username):
        user_error = "Must be between 3 and 25 characters"
        username = ""
    else:
        username = request.form['username']

    if not password.isalpha():
        pass_error = "Please enter Password"
        password = ""
    else:
        password = request.form['password']

    if not verifypword.isalpha():
        verifypass_error = "Please enter password"
        verifypword = ""

    elif verifypword != password:
        verifypass_error = "Passwords do not match"

    else:
        verifypword = request.form['verifypass']

    if not re.match("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", email):
        email_error = "Email must contain @ and ."

    else:
        email = request.form['email']

    if not pass_error and not user_error and not verifypass_error:
        return redirect('/welcome'.format(username))
    else:
        template = jinja_env.get_template('index.html')
        return template.render(user_error = user_error, 
                                pass_error = pass_error,
                                verifypass_error = verifypass_error,
                                email_error = email_error,
                                username = username,
                                email = email)


@app.route('/welcome', methods = ['POST'])
def welcome():
    template = jinja_env.get_template('welcome.html')
    return template.render


app.run()
```

Comment: You haven't said what your "little problem" actually is.

Comment: Please describe the Problem to the point

Comment: Describe your problem please, provide as much detail as possible. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17536445)

Comment: My apologies. After filling in the fields and hitting submit button I'm getting a bad request error when redirecting to the welcome page.

Comment: @Jared_5714 You didn't post which request you actually submit. I cleaned your code and then it works. Please try the code in the answer or provide us with more detail if you really want to know why you got a bad request error.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [wtforms](/questions/tagged/wtforms) in this case. It is difficult to know what your problem is, but I hope that you can use the following working code that returns a welcome redirect if user has submitted a password with the registration form.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template
import cgi
import os
import jinja2
import re
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, PasswordField, validators

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    password = PasswordField('New Password', [
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Repeat Password')

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

@app.route("/")
def index():
    template = jinja_env.get_template('index.html')
    return template.render(form=RegistrationForm())


@app.route("/validate-signup", methods = ['POST'])
def validate_signup():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    pass_error = None
    if not password.isalpha():
        pass_error = "Please enter Password"
    template = jinja_env.get_template('index.html')

    if not pass_error:
        return redirect('/welcome')
    else:
        return template.render(username=username, form=RegistrationForm())


@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    template = jinja_env.get_template('welcome.html')
    return template.render()


app.run()
```

**template/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/validate-signup">
    {{ form.username.label }} {{ form.username }}
    {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit to me">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**template/welcome.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
WELCOME
</body>
</html>
```